# Google Cloud Load Balancer Local File Writing issue

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I am facing a problem when hosted a PHP application in an apache2 server in centos7 using Google Cloud Load Balancer. We are generating a report querying the database and writing the result into a PHPExcel object. Had set a cookie generated affinity to 600seconds, request timeout as 300secs and connection draining timeout as 300 secs. Working completely fine in a single instance but failing in an instance group environment. Please suggest us with a solution. With load balancer request failed to get any response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal, it should work if:
- All the permissions are set in the instance group
- The object has the proper config for multiple access
- I don't believe that session affinity and connection draining has something to do with the issue
I can't suggest a solution without knowing more details. Check this points and tell us if is all ok with it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This issue has been solved. But I am not sure about the reason for which that error was occurring. Maybe the issue was with either startup script of instance template or cloud proxy host authentication.

Comment: Good to know that is working. The other subjects you mention could have also have had influenced the behavior. For a next occasion I recommend you to include the information if you are using startup script or any other non default configuration.